# ReactJS State not getting updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am updating a state from child.

```
getInitialState : function(){
        return{
            VotedForTopic : false

        };
    },

updateVotedState:function(){
        this.setState({VotedForTopic:true});
        console.log(this.state.VotedForTopic)
    },
```

I am calling updateVotedState from the child when some action is performed to change the VotedForTopic state to true.But the state is not getting updated it remains false.
What could be the problem

Comment: `this.setState(newState)` is async. it happens very fast, but you can move the `console.log` into your render method and you'll see it update.

Answer (score 2):

You can update `parent` state from `child` using callback which passed to `child` through `props`, like this

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            VotedForTopic: false
        };
    },

    updateVotedState: function () {
        this.setState({ VotedForTopic: true });
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <p>{'Current State:: ' + this.state.VotedForTopic} </p>
            <Child onUpdateVote={this.updateVotedState} />
        </div>;
    }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <a onClick={this.props.onUpdateVote}>updateVotedState</a>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/19023/)

Answer (score 1):

Does the state never update or are you relying on the `console.log` ? From the docs:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

try passing a callback to `setState`:

```
updateVotedState:function(){
    var that = this;
    this.setState({VotedForTopic:true}, function(){
        console.log(that.state.VotedForTopic)
    });
},
```

Comment: this will show as true.. but then when i click on an item which checks the value of  VotedForTopic before doing some action shows the value as false.